# Scenario hooks only valid on scenario outlines?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

We're using Cucumber and Selenium with Ruby.  After reading the [documentation on hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) I've tried my hand at setting a few tags to set (for example) some environment variables.

Here's a contrived example that demonstrates the problem.

When I establish a `Before` hook like so:

```
Before('@tag1', '@tag2') do
  puts "in the before hook!"
end
```

It'll take effect with a scenario defined like so:

```
@tag1 @tag2
Scenario Outline: This is a test scenario
  Given I run my first step for "<user>"
  Then I complete my test

@firstrun
Scenarios:
|user|
|fred|

@secondrun
Scenarios:
|user|
|barney|
```

..however if I move `@tag1` and `@tag2` to the individual scenarios and not the scenario outline, the hook is never called, for instance:

```
@secondrun @tag1 @tag2
Scenarios:
|user|
|barney|
```

Is it possible to 'hook in' individual scenarios, or just the outlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically with scenario outlines the table of values you're testing is tied to that, not separate scenarios.

E.g

```
ScenarioOutline
    Given I am on gmails website
    When I login as <user> with <password>
    Then I am able to view my primary inbox
    Example:
    | user | password |
    | Fred | xd13#%&  |
```