# Cucumber Ordered Tagged Hooks

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am trying to use an ordered, tagged hook using Java cucumber. For example:

@Before("@quicklink", order = 20)

The compiler doesn't seem to like it. Is it not possible to have an ordered, tagged hook ? Seems like a reasonable combination of functionality. If so, what is the syntax ?

thnx

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the same but in a different way

@Before(value = "@quicklink", order = 20)

But, this may create odd issues if you have another hook method with the same order number for other tests. Like both the methods will run for this scenario.

So I suggest using the tagged expressions if you are using same order like as follows:

For other methods use
@Before(value = "~@quicklink", order = 20)
this will make sure this scenario will never run on other methods

and for this scenario alone,

@Before(value = "@quicklink", order = 20)

this will make sure the above method will never run for those.

If you are using 2x version of tagged expressions in your project, you can replace the '~' with  a 'not'

This might come handy if you want to replace a method in hooks class in just a specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

`@Before(value = "@quicklink", order = 20)`

Comment: @WalterKelt I think that it a separate issue/question. This IS the answer to your question ("what is the syntax for an ordered, tagged hook?"). If it's not working in your specific case you should ask a separate question. Perhaps you're doing something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420474/scenario-hooks-only-valid-on-scenario-outlines ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the order for hooks like this:

Annotated method style (if you are using cucumber-java):

```
@Before(order = 10)
public void doSomething(){
    // Do something before each scenario
}
```

Lambda style (if you are using cucumber-java8):

```
Before(10, () -> {
    // Do something before each scenario
});
```

Comment: Doesn’t address the desire to use both order  & tag in the same annotation. Ordering  and tagging by themselves is straightforward. How do I combine their usage ?

Comment: You're right, I didn't properly read the question. Tbh, I'm not using ordered, tagged hooks and while that sounds like a reasonable conbination, I wonder how it would work out in practice (does tag precede order, or the other way around? etc). What have you tried so far and which errors you are getting? (My next step would be to try and figure it out from the code and/or ask in Cucumber Slack #help-cucumber-jvm channel)

Comment: in practice, I would expect the following behavior. When the "order" is hit, then a decision to execute is made based on the tag. Thus far I have tried to implement in my cuke code but intellij (with cuke plugin) is complaining thus won't compile. I will look at the cuke source code today to see if this is supported. I am expecting to be disappointed :-).

Comment: Tbh, so am I. But good luck! And if you really need it, maybe this is something you could implement?

Comment: Seems that some level of support is provided, however there seems to be a functional difference depending on whether a scenario outline is used or not. For example, the compiler is okay with:  @Before(value ="@hbtest",order = 2). But when I run it with an scenario outline example tag, the tag is ignore by the "before hook logic". the method is never run. Oh well..